# NETBEANS 8.2 error al desinstalar

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy intentando desinstalar netbeans, ya que no consigo que arranque, y quería realizar una nueva instalación limpia, pero no lo consigo, me genera el siguiente error.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006fe46adf, pid=6592, tid=0x0000000000000a0c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000016c43800):  JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2572, stack(0x0000000018800000,0x0000000018900000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00000000188ff290, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000e64900
RSP=0x00000000188ff238, RBP=0x00000000188ff420, RSI=0x00000000000000d5, RDI=0x0000000016c439f8
R8 =0x0000000000e64900, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x00000000188fc8f0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000188ff440, R14=0x00000000188ff408, R15=0x0000000016c43800
RIP=0x000000006fe46adf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000188ff238)
0x00000000188ff238:   000000006fcd9d36 0000000000000000
0x00000000188ff248:   0000000016c439f8 00000000000000d5
0x00000000188ff258:   0000000000e64900 0000000016c439f8
0x00000000188ff268:   000000006fcda6f9 0000000000e64900
0x00000000188ff278:   0000736973a83faa 0000000016c43800
0x00000000188ff288:   00000000ffffffff 0000000000000000
0x00000000188ff298:   0000000000000000 0000000016c43800
0x00000000188ff2a8:   0000000016b210e0 0000000000000000
0x00000000188ff2b8:   00000000000005cc 0000000000000000
0x00000000188ff2c8:   0000000000000000 0000000016c43800
0x00000000188ff2d8:   000000006f208ff8 0000000016c43800
0x00000000188ff2e8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000188ff2f8:   0000736973a83f5a 0000000000000005
0x00000000188ff308:   0000000016c43800 0000000000000001
0x00000000188ff318:   00000000169d5be0 0020006100740000
0x00000000188ff328:   0061002000650000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006fe46adf)
0x000000006fe46abf:   99 03 00 cc 33 c0 48 8b 5c 24 40 48 8b 74 24 48
0x000000006fe46acf:   48 83 c4 30 5f c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 8b c1
0x000000006fe46adf:   0f b7 10 48 83 c0 02 66 85 d2 75 f4 48 2b c1 48
0x000000006fe46aef:   d1 f8 48 ff c8 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 45 33 c0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000188ff290 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016c43800
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000e64900 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000000188ff238 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016c43800
RBP=0x00000000188ff420 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016c43800
RSI=0x00000000000000d5 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000016c439f8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000e64900 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000188fc8f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016c43800
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000188ff440 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016c43800
R14=0x00000000188ff408 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016c43800
R15=0x0000000016c43800 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000018800000,0x0000000018900000],  sp=0x00000000188ff238,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 912  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getDisplayNameOf(JJI)Ljava/lang/String; (0 bytes) @ 0x000000000301b789 [0x000000000301b740+0x49]
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$1600(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;+4
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/String;+15
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run()V+7
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x0000000016c43800 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2572, stack(0x0000000018800000,0x0000000018900000)]
  0x0000000016c25800 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5600, stack(0x0000000018500000,0x0000000018600000)]
  0x0000000016c19800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=4972, stack(0x0000000018400000,0x0000000018500000)]
  0x0000000016b18800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2568, stack(0x0000000017b80000,0x0000000017c80000)]
  0x0000000016b29000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=5576, stack(0x0000000017a80000,0x0000000017b80000)]
  0x0000000016b28000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2556, stack(0x0000000017980000,0x0000000017a80000)]
  0x0000000015b54800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11256, stack(0x00000000166a0000,0x00000000167a0000)]
  0x0000000015ac6000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4892, stack(0x00000000165a0000,0x00000000166a0000)]
  0x0000000015ac5800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8268, stack(0x00000000164a0000,0x00000000165a0000)]
  0x0000000015abd000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1336, stack(0x00000000163a0000,0x00000000164a0000)]
  0x0000000015aba000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1080, stack(0x00000000162a0000,0x00000000163a0000)]
  0x0000000015ab7000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1280, stack(0x00000000161a0000,0x00000000162a0000)]
  0x0000000015ab6000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1060, stack(0x00000000160a0000,0x00000000161a0000)]
  0x0000000002cf9000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12104, stack(0x0000000015e90000,0x0000000015f90000)]
  0x0000000002cf5800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9844, stack(0x0000000015990000,0x0000000015a90000)]
  0x0000000002a3e800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=7044, stack(0x0000000002b00000,0x0000000002c00000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000013bba000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000015890000,0x0000000015990000] [id=7972]
  0x0000000015b05800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000167a0000,0x00000000168a0000] [id=6588]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 21614K [0x00000000fab00000, 0x00000000fd580000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 64% used [0x00000000fab00000,0x00000000fc01b9d8,0x00000000fcb80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000fd080000,0x00000000fd080000,0x00000000fd580000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000fcb80000,0x00000000fcb80000,0x00000000fd080000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f5580000, 0x00000000fab00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f5580000)
 Metaspace       used 16803K, capacity 17004K, committed 17408K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2123K, capacity 2199K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000120c0000,0x0000000012150000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011940000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006f83c720
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012950000, 0x0000000012d50000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000012d50000, 0x0000000013150000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000d60000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=3204Kb max_used=3204Kb free=242555Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002d00000, 0x0000000003030000, 0x0000000011d00000]
 total_blobs=1439 nmethods=926 adapters=426
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.088 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000  922       1       javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI::getFileChooser (5 bytes)
Event: 1.088 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000 nmethod 922 0x0000000003020bd0 code [0x0000000003020d20, 0x0000000003020e30]
Event: 1.088 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000  923       1       java.awt.MediaEntry::getID (5 bytes)
Event: 1.088 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000 nmethod 923 0x0000000003020e90 code [0x0000000003020fe0, 0x00000000030210f0]
Event: 1.089 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000  924       3       java.awt.Color::equals (27 bytes)
Event: 1.089 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000 nmethod 924 0x0000000003021150 code [0x00000000030212c0, 0x00000000030217b0]
Event: 1.090 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000  925       3       java.awt.Component::isEnabled (5 bytes)
Event: 1.090 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000 nmethod 925 0x0000000003021890 code [0x00000000030219e0, 0x0000000003021bd0]
Event: 1.090 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000  926       1       java.nio.DirectByteBuffer::isReadOnly (2 bytes)
Event: 1.090 Thread 0x0000000015ac6000 nmethod 926 0x0000000003021c50 code [0x0000000003021da0, 0x0000000003021eb0]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (8 events):
Event: 0.385 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Uncommon trap: reason=null_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x0000000002ed24b8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 0.476 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002f381e0 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 62
Event: 0.615 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002e9eb90 method=java.lang.String.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z @ 25
Event: 0.886 Thread 0x0000000016c19800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002ede1a8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 0.886 Thread 0x0000000016c19800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002ede1a8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 0.886 Thread 0x0000000016c19800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002ede1a8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 0.886 Thread 0x0000000016c19800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002ede1a8 method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 1.031 Thread 0x0000000016c19800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002fe70f8 method=java.util.Hashtable.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 48

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.027 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000fab07f90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims
Event: 0.106 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fac7e0e0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.106 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fac7e4d8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fac827b8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000fac82bb0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.385 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000002ed22d8 to 0x0000000002ed24a9
Event: 0.476 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000fb983088) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 0.511 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000fba4ea30) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.513 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000fba5c120) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.584 Thread 0x0000000002a3e800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000fbb445a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.917 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$5 done
Event: 0.982 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$18
Event: 0.982 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$18 done
Event: 0.982 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$ColumnComparator$1
Event: 0.982 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$ColumnComparator$1 done
Event: 0.984 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$11
Event: 0.984 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$11 done
Event: 1.031 Thread 0x0000000016c19800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x0000000002fe70f8
Event: 1.032 Thread 0x0000000016c19800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000002fe70f8 sp=0x00000000184fcca0
Event: 1.032 Thread 0x0000000016c19800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002d4582a sp=0x00000000184fcc58 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff665aa0000 - 0x00007ff665ad7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffadfdd0000 - 0x00007ffadffab000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffadd9e0000 - 0x00007ffadda8e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffadc2d0000 - 0x00007ffadc519000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffada770000 - 0x00007ffada7ee000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffadfbb0000 - 0x00007ffadfc51000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffadd940000 - 0x00007ffadd9dd000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffaddc80000 - 0x00007ffaddcd9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffade110000 - 0x00007ffade235000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffaddf00000 - 0x00007ffade04a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffadd110000 - 0x00007ffadd12e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffade0e0000 - 0x00007ffade107000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffadd130000 - 0x00007ffadd2b9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffadc520000 - 0x00007ffadc5ba000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffadc6d0000 - 0x00007ffadc7c6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffacf1b0000 - 0x00007ffacf417000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.0_none_108e4f62dfe5d999\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffadf8b0000 - 0x00007ffadfba9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffadc7d0000 - 0x00007ffadc83a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffade050000 - 0x00007ffade07d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x000000006fe10000 - 0x000000006fee2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006f020000 - 0x000000006f8bc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffadd930000 - 0x00007ffadd938000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffada850000 - 0x00007ffada873000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffacd3f0000 - 0x00007ffacd3f9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffad6fc0000 - 0x00007ffad6fca000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffadd750000 - 0x00007ffadd7bc000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffada820000 - 0x00007ffada84b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffadd2c0000 - 0x00007ffadd309000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000070210000 - 0x000000007021f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000701e0000 - 0x0000000070209000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00000000701c0000 - 0x00000000701d6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffade470000 - 0x00007ffadf8a7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffadd7d0000 - 0x00007ffadd87a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffadca10000 - 0x00007ffadd102000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffade080000 - 0x00007ffade0d1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffadc270000 - 0x00007ffadc281000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffadc220000 - 0x00007ffadc26c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffadc2b0000 - 0x00007ffadc2c5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffadbce0000 - 0x00007ffadbcf7000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00007ffadb750000 - 0x00007ffadb784000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ffadbde0000 - 0x00007ffadbe05000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ffadc150000 - 0x00007ffadc179000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffadbcd0000 - 0x00007ffadbcdb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000000006ff30000 - 0x000000006ff4a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffadbb30000 - 0x00007ffadbb8c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffadb8d0000 - 0x00007ffadb907000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ffadd7c0000 - 0x00007ffadd7c8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffad3340000 - 0x00007ffad3356000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ffad3320000 - 0x00007ffad333a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000000006ff10000 - 0x000000006ff21000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000002a20000 - 0x0000000002a27000     C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\nbi-4731135297064739304.tmp
0x00007ffade300000 - 0x00007ffade444000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x000000006fc70000 - 0x000000006fe08000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x00007ffade240000 - 0x00007ffade2ff000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ffada980000 - 0x00007ffadaa15000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ffaddb10000 - 0x00007ffaddc76000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffad92b0000 - 0x00007ffad92da000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000000006fc20000 - 0x000000006fc67000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x00007ffac7e70000 - 0x00007ffac7f16000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.15063.0_none_43a14f3b47f396e6\comctl32.dll
0x00007ffadd880000 - 0x00007ffadd91e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ffada1d0000 - 0x00007ffada366000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
0x00007ffaba7d0000 - 0x00007ffaba8f7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
0x00007ffad2830000 - 0x00007ffad2d61000     C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll
0x00007ffad3ea0000 - 0x00007ffad404c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x00007ffad8ff0000 - 0x00007ffad9047000     C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll
0x00007ffad2e60000 - 0x00007ffad2ed6000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
0x00007ffad3b50000 - 0x00007ffad3bdf000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcp110_win.dll
0x00007ffacb790000 - 0x00007ffacb8b1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\opengl32.dll
0x00007ffad3950000 - 0x00007ffad397c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x000000006fbd0000 - 0x000000006fc12000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\t2k.dll
0x00007ffad0510000 - 0x00007ffad052b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffad4ee0000 - 0x00007ffad4eeb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\drprov.dll
0x00007ffadb3c0000 - 0x00007ffadb415000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINSTA.dll
0x00007ffad4c00000 - 0x00007ffad4c16000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntlanman.dll
0x00007ffabd9c0000 - 0x00007ffabd9e0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\davclnt.dll
0x00007ffacc050000 - 0x00007ffacc05c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
0x00007ffad39a0000 - 0x00007ffad39b6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wkscli.dll
0x00007ffacc0a0000 - 0x00007ffacc0b2000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
0x00007ffadb9c0000 - 0x00007ffadb9cd000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\netutils.dll
0x00007ffab8c50000 - 0x00007ffab8c9a000     C:\Windows\System32\dlnashext.dll
0x00007ffab8be0000 - 0x00007ffab8c4d000     C:\Windows\System32\PlayToDevice.dll
0x00007ffaca630000 - 0x00007ffaca64e000     C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll
0x00007ffad1ae0000 - 0x00007ffad1b47000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x00007ffadada0000 - 0x00007ffadadc8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007ffac5b50000 - 0x00007ffac5d2f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wpdshext.dll
0x00007ffacec30000 - 0x00007ffacedc5000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.15063.0_none_9055be80f37df5c1\gdiplus.dll
0x00007ffad4d80000 - 0x00007ffad4e1c000     C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceApi.dll
0x00007ffadd310000 - 0x00007ffadd74b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x00007ffadc5c0000 - 0x00007ffadc616000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00007ffadc290000 - 0x00007ffadc2a1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007ffadc840000 - 0x00007ffadca09000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007ffad3500000 - 0x00007ffad3536000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorShell.dll
0x00007ffad55c0000 - 0x00007ffad55e5000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorAPI.dll
0x00007ffad9290000 - 0x00007ffad92a3000     C:\Windows\System32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ffad8f80000 - 0x00007ffad8f90000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll
0x00007ffad04b0000 - 0x00007ffad04bc000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
0x00007ffadc120000 - 0x00007ffadc150000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
0x00007ffaccb80000 - 0x00007ffaccd29000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Pol\AppData\Local\Temp\ -Xmx256m -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans -Dnetbeans.default_cachedir_root=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache 
java_command: org.netbeans.installer.Installer --target nb-base 8.2.0.0.201610071157 --force-uninstall
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\\NBI32865.tmp\uninstall.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
USERNAME=Pol
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.0)

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 8335212k(4310472k free), swap 16723820k(11405608k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed Apr 26 00:07:33 2017
elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)
```

Muchas Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Hay que borrar el Icono de Modo Dios de Windows, para que pueda funcionar el instalador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, también tuve ese problema y ya lo solucioné.
Tal vez tienes creada la carpeta de GodMode? sólo tienes que eliminar esa carpeta y listo, a mi me funcionó eso. Creo que incluso podrás volver a correr netbeans o desintalarlo, lo que quieras.

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón ayer probé y ya se lanza el instalador correctamente. Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 1):

El error que estás recibiendo es un [**bug (error) reportado hace poco en NetBeans**](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178846).

Algunos datos del bug son los siguientes:

```
Type: Bug
Status:RESOLVED
Priority: P4
Resolution: Incomplete
Affects Version/s: 8u121
Fix Version/s: None
```

**Dates**

```
Created:    2017-04-14 18:00
Updated:    2017-04-16 22:38
Resolved:   2017-04-16 22:37
```

En el detalle del bug se puede apreciar un mensaje casi idéntico al tuyo:

```
A DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM : 
# 
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
# 
# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005e806adf, pid=9148, tid=0x0000000000001e28 
# 
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13) 
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops) 
# Problematic frame: 
# C [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf] 
# 
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows 
# 
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: 
# http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp 
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. 
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Y se puede determinar que el problema se encuentra aquí, en el archivo `msvcr100.dll`:

```
# Problematic frame: 
# C [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf] 
# 
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

Aunque como se indica más arriba, en la página el bug está marcado como

```
Status:RESOLVED
```

pero luego pone:

```
Resolution: Incomplete
```

Lo cual es algo confuso. Dice que está **RESUELTO** pero al mismo tiempo dice que la resolución es **Incompleta**, lo cual puede significar que no está del todo controlado y puede aparecer en algunos sistemas operativos o escenarios diversos.

Como posible solución. Asegúrate primero que tienes todo actualizado:  sistema operativo, versión de Java y [última versión de NetBeans disponible en su sitio web de descargas](https://netbeans.org/downloads/). Nótese que el bug ha sido resuelto parcialmente el `16-04-2017`, por lo que no te puedes fiar si estás intentando re-instalar una versión de NetBeans descargada antes de esa fecha.

Comment: Muchas gracias, aún intentando instalar la última versión de Netbeans sigo con problemas, al abrir el instalador me sale la barra de carga del configurador de instalación i se cierra, lo mismo me pasa con el uninstaller, así que estoy totalmente atascado, no puedo montar ninguna versión de netbeans, ni puedo eliminarla.

Comment: ¿Y si pones a salvo en otro lugar tu carpeta de proyectos y borras todo manualmente? Luego intentas instalar con la última descarga de NetBeans, después de haber reiniciado tu PC.

Comment: Perdón por contestar tan tarde, he estado liado.
Que tendría que eliminar para probarlo, intente eliminar todos los directorios de netbeans, i reiniciar, pero sigo con el mismo problema al volver a instalar, se abre el instalador, se carga la barra y se cierra estoy desesperado ya.
Muchas gracias.